# how could pass dynamic variable with static text in template custom filter in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

How could I use the dynamic parameter with static text in template to custom filter ?

in view.py you can use this way to pass many parameters

```
message = 'hello {} this is {}'.format(from_user, to_user)
```

how could I translate above code to template.html code ?

I want do following condition with multi args for example like this :

```
{% if users|is_user_authorised_to_view_page:'users/<page_id>/<username>/'.format(page.id, user.username) %}
    {# do this ... #}
{% endif %}
```

how could I do that? I searched but didn't find any solution , thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

```
{% with page.id|get_url:user.username as url %}   
 {% if users|is_user_authorised_to_view_page:url %}
        {# do this ... #}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

create another filter

```
@register.filter
def get_url(page_id, username):
    return 'users/{0}/{1}/'.format(int(page_id), username)
```

Comment: it's show me an error 'operator expected' here '''is_user_authorised_to_view_page:page.id:user.username'''

Comment: can you post the error? where exactly are you getting the error? and please share the template filter definition

Comment: My bad, i was doing it wrong, kindly see my updated answer

Comment: You might be interested in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Comment: it's work now with no errors, but the values received are static values like ''page.id" and "user.username" no values

Comment: I can further simply it, once you make me understand what exactly are you trying to do, like sharing your "is_user_authorised_to_view" filter's definition